# AMPScript Lookuprows with multiple criteria in the same column

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, content-builder

Is there a way to use multiple criteria when using the lookuprows ampscript function?

Example (which SFMC gives an error in that I can’t use the same column twice):

```ampscript
%%[

set @Category = "News"
set @Category2 = "Events"
set @rows = LookupRows("Content","Category", @Category,"Category", @Category2)

]%%
```

My work around is doing two Lookuprows with two FOR Loops which feels extremely inefficient.

Comment: [LookupRows](https://ampscript.guide/lookuprows/) and all the other AMPscript lookup functions use AND operators with exact matches.

Comment: Thank you @AdamSpriggs I will try this out later today.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs I tried linking two LookupRows with an "And" and that didn't give me an error in Preview & Test, but the row count didn't combine and so the use case didn't render.  So is it not possible to look up multiple values in a single column?